# using other programming language's library with phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

to be honest I've never done phoenix or elixir programming before but I would like to give them a try for a new application I am building... for my need I will need to do some external API interaction of some online web services, and those services provide some kind of libraries to use with their api, but most of them are for "php, python, and ruby", I don't want to reinvent the wheel because it's a lot of work, is there any way to use those libraries with phoenix even if they are for other language ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without some pain in the butt and complicating your app stack. But hey, you can help the community and write some packages for those APIs :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for 99% you will have to create the libraries to use these external APIs on your own or using already existing hex packages. If these APIs you mentioned are RESTful, interaction with them should be way much easier.

If you craft something useful, don't forget to cover it with tests and register in hex. Good luck!

Comment: Then you know where the resources are and how to get them. Check out [this](https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#rest-and-api) link.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any easy solutions. You either write an Elixir version of the API or you in effect create a mini-proxy in the language of choice and communicate with that either via BEAM ports or a more standard IPC method like tcp client/server over localhost.

There are some tools to help with all this, erlports has good support for moving data between the BEAM and python and ruby.

http://erlport.org/